# Get and manipulate variable value from inside a webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

In my code there is a variable inside the main .Im using `var size = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#produto > script').innerHTML);` to get that said variable, but it returns the text of html in a string. I tried using the variable inside the querySelector but had no success.
When im using console on broswer when I type `SKUsCorTamanho[20]` it returns `{ProdutoId: "209923", Codigo: "193658125505", Tamanho: "20", PrecoDe: "R$ 0,00", PrecoPor: "R$ 799,99", …}`. I need someway that I can send `for (i 20 to 40){var size[i] =SKUsCorTamanho[i] }` or something like this. And can use things like `SKUsCorTamanho[20].PrecoPor` to return `"R$ 799,99"`.

Comment: can you expain a little bit more? or if you can share the code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cw8pexfy/. Its a web scrapper to get sneaker data from nike.com.br. I'm using puppeteer to emulate broswer.